# Unnatural to read in data files line by line

Tags: c++, database, qt, qtableview

Filestreams allow us to iterate over the lines of a file. When we split the line, e.g. by a comma or space, the usual thing is to add this resulting vector to another container.

The result might be a `Vector< Vector<String> >` (or your flavor of containers).

When I give this to a `QTableView` using a `QAbstractTableModel`, the rows and columns are inverted: the outer container actually denotes the rows, while the inner container denotes columns.

I am unsure what to do, since I want to present the data, allow some editing actions (editing the *model*), and then write it out into a comparable file.

My data will be around 200,000 rows (people) by 300 columns (values), and it is actually *slower* to read into the vector from file, but *faster* to present in the `QTableView` when I read the matrix in an *inverted* way.
When writing it to another file, it is not so easy this time to write out a transposed vector compared to the normal way in which you can just:

```
for (int iter = 0; ....; ...)
{
    row = matrix[iter].join(" ")
    file.write(row)
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? It has to be displayed in the inverted way. When connecting the model to the view should I transpose, or should I fill the matrix originally in an inverted way?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reexamine your data structures. A much nicer, from a cache-coherency point of view, way of doing it might be to have the following:

```
struct Line {
    QString str;
    QVector<short> splitPoints; // 2 points per each substring (begin, length)
};

struct File {
    QVector<Line> lines;
}
```

Of course you'd want full-fledged implementation for the `Line`, including convenience operators etc., but this gives you an idea. When returning constant strings from the `Line`, you'd want to use `QStringRef` to avoid copying stuff.